# Position af background image according to the bootm of the image

Tags: css

I need the background image to be horizontally centered, but vertically the bottom of the image should always be in y=350px.

I have tried with calc(100% - 350px) but that isn't the right answer. The problem is that it is calculating from the top of the image instead of the bottom.

Comment: Can you post your code, please ?

Answer (score 0):

`background-position: center;` should make your job. See the doc [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp).

Comment: It won't place the bottom of the background image in y=350px regardless of screen width

Comment: can you try a `background-position: 0 0 350px 0;` ?

Comment: `background-position: 0 -350px;` ?

Comment: That will place the top of the background in .350, at if I made the image 700px heright it would work if the screen width os the same as the image width, but if the screen width changes, the height of the image will also change and then the image is misplaced.

Comment: Well anyway, i'm pretty sure there is a bad HTML DOM structure behind this... cna you put all your code plz

Answer (score 0):

In most Browsers ( [caniuse background edge offsets](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-background-offsets) ) you can now set the `background-position` property with 4 values instead of just 2. So you can do something like

```
 .element {
      background-position: left 10px top 30px
}
```

Which will position the `image` at `10px` from the `left` and at `30px` from the `top`. If you don't include a `px` value it is defaulted to `0`.

In your case, see snippet below

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/250x200");
  width: 250px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Read more here -> [background position 4 values](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-position/#article-header-id-1)